# Multidimensional array key naming on creating

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am running a foreach loop on an object that is returned to me from UPS that gets the customers history of their shipment. I am trying to nest all of the information using the tracking number has the parent key. I can't seem to get it working.

```
public function getUpsHistoryArray($tracking_number)
{

    $upsParams = $this->trackUps($tracking_number, '1');

    if ($upsParams->Shipment->Package->Activity->ActivityLocation)
    {
        foreach ($upsParams->Shipment->Package->Activity as $activity)
            if ($activity->ActivityLocation->Address->City)
                $newParams[] = array(
                    'location' => $activity->ActivityLocation->Address->City.', ' . $activity->ActivityLocation->Address->StateProvinceCode,
                    'date' => date('n/d/Y', strtotime($activity->Date)),
                    'time' => date('g:i a', strtotime($activity->Time)),
                    'activity' => (string)$activity->Status->StatusType->Description
                    );
    }

    return $newParams;
}

array(2) {
[0]=>
  array(10) {
  [0]=>
   array(4) {
   ["location"]=>
   string(10) "GOLDEN, CO"
   ["date"]=>
   string(9) "9/15/2014"
   ["time"]=>
   string(8) "11:27 am"
   ["activity"]=>
   string(9) "DELIVERED"
 }
 [1]=>
  array(4) {
   ["location"]=>
   string(17) "COMMERCE CITY, CO"
   ["date"]=>
   string(9) "9/15/2014"
   ["time"]=>
   string(7) "6:00 am"
   ["activity"]=>
   string(16) "OUT FOR DELIVERY"
}
}
 [1]=>
  array(10) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
  ["location"]=>
  string(10) "GOLDEN, CO"
  ["date"]=>
  string(9) "9/15/2014"
  ["time"]=>
  string(8) "11:27 am"
  ["activity"]=>
  string(9) "DELIVERED"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
  ["location"]=>
  string(17) "COMMERCE CITY, CO"
  ["date"]=>
  string(9) "9/15/2014"
  ["time"]=>
  string(7) "6:00 am"
  ["activity"]=>
  string(16) "OUT FOR DELIVERY"
}
```

I would like it to display

```
array(2) {
[1ZXXXXXXXXXXXX]=>
  array(10) {
  [0]=>
   array(4) {
   ["location"]=>
   string(10) "GOLDEN, CO"
   ["date"]=>
   string(9) "9/15/2014"
   ["time"]=>
   string(8) "11:27 am"
   ["activity"]=>
   string(9) "DELIVERED"
 }
 [1]=>
  array(4) {
   ["location"]=>
   string(17) "COMMERCE CITY, CO"
   ["date"]=>
   string(9) "9/15/2014"
   ["time"]=>
   string(7) "6:00 am"
   ["activity"]=>
   string(16) "OUT FOR DELIVERY"
}
}
 [1ZXXXXXXXXXXXX]=>
  array(10) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
  ["location"]=>
  string(10) "GOLDEN, CO"
  ["date"]=>
  string(9) "9/15/2014"
  ["time"]=>
  string(8) "11:27 am"
  ["activity"]=>
  string(9) "DELIVERED"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
  ["location"]=>
  string(17) "COMMERCE CITY, CO"
  ["date"]=>
  string(9) "9/15/2014"
  ["time"]=>
  string(7) "6:00 am"
  ["activity"]=>
  string(16) "OUT FOR DELIVERY"
}
```

I have tried

```
public function getUpsHistoryArray($tracking_number)
{

    $upsParams = $this->trackUps($tracking_number, '1');

    if ($upsParams->Shipment->Package->Activity->ActivityLocation)
    {
        foreach ($upsParams->Shipment->Package->Activity as $activity)
            if ($activity->ActivityLocation->Address->City)
                $newParams[$upsParams->Shipment->Package->TrackingNumber] = array(
                    'location' => $activity->ActivityLocation->Address->City.', ' . $activity->ActivityLocation->Address->StateProvinceCode,
                    'date' => date('n/d/Y', strtotime($activity->Date)),
                    'time' => date('g:i a', strtotime($activity->Time)),
                    'activity' => (string)$activity->Status->StatusType->Description
                    );
    }

    return $newParams;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is $tracking_number == $upsParams->Shipment->Package->TrackingNumber ?

if so... try

```
public function getUpsHistoryArray($tracking_number)
{

    $upsParams = $this->trackUps($tracking_number, '1');

    if ($upsParams->Shipment->Package->Activity->ActivityLocation)
    {

        $new_params = array($tracking_number => array());

        foreach ($upsParams->Shipment->Package->Activity as $activity)
            if ($activity->ActivityLocation->Address->City)
                $newParams[$tracking_number][] = array(
                    'location' => $activity->ActivityLocation->Address->City.', ' . $activity->ActivityLocation->Address->StateProvinceCode,
                    'date' => date('n/d/Y', strtotime($activity->Date)),
                    'time' => date('g:i a', strtotime($activity->Time)),
                    'activity' => (string)$activity->Status->StatusType->Description
                    );
    }

    return $newParams;
}
```

the key difference is newParams[$tracking_number][] = ...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$newParams[$upsParams->Shipment->Package->TrackingNumber][] = array(
                    'location' => $activity->ActivityLocation->Address->City.', '
                     . $activity->ActivityLocation->Address->StateProvinceCode,
                    'date' => date('n/d/Y', strtotime($activity->Date)),
                    'time' => date('g:i a', strtotime($activity->Time)),
                    'activity' => (string)$activity->Status->StatusType->Description
                    );
```

But you won't get exactly what you show because multiple keys (tracking number) can't have the same value.